# Mongoose - Query returns nothing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query:

```
app.get('/matches/:latMin/:latMax/:lonMin/:lonMax', function(req, res){
    var matches = City.find({
        "latitude": {$gt : String(req.param.latMin), $lt : String(req.params.latMax) }, 
        "longitude" : {$gt : String(req.param.lonMin), $lt : String(req.param.lonMax)}
    });
    matches.exec(function(err, match){
                 if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                     return res.send(err);
                 }
                console.log(match);
                res.json(match);
            });     
});
```

Here is my schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model('City', new Schema({
    zip : {type : String, default: ''},
    latitude : {type : String, default: ''},
    longitude : {type: String, default: ''},
    city : {type: String, default: ''},
    state : {type: String, default: ''},
    county : {type: String, default: ''}
}), 'locations');
```

When I run the query in the Mongo shell, the expected results are sent.  However, the log in the above quotes returns [].  Is there something wrong I'm doing here?

Comment: Shouldn't you be converting `req.param.latMin`, `req.param.latMax`, etc. to numbers instead of casting them to string (which they already are)?

Comment: I think intuitively your lon, lat is numbers and you'd want to do $gt, $lt in numbers?

Comment: Right, why are you storing your `latitude` and `longitude` values in the doc as strings instead of numbers?

Comment: i suggest you remove apostrophe  from `latitude` and `longitude`

Comment: It seems to work fine in the mongo shell.  I have them as strings because I'm not doing any number operations on them.  They're like the zip code, I'm going to be adding/subtracting them so storing them as numbers is useless.

Comment: But you're trying to use numerical comparison operators on them. "9.0" > "20.0" but 9.0 < 20.0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to use `req.param` or it is just a typo. Anyway, [`req.param`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param) is deprecated and you should use `req.params`.

I have set up your scenario and queries are working. Replace the `var matches` in your code for the following:

```
var matches = City.find({
    "latitude": {$gt : String(req.params.latMin), $lt : String(req.params.latMax) }, 
    "longitude" : {$gt : String(req.params.lonMin), $lt : String(req.params.lonMax)}
});
```